# How do I select a div with its children as handles using jQuerys Selectable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div which contains two elements which dont fill up that div. I want selecting the elements to select the containing div instead. Also, I want that clicking in the div but outside the elements doesnt select the element (and triggers a deselect). How do i do this?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U5cmy/1/

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you want to do? By selecting parent div you want to automatically select children divs?

Comment: I want the parent div to be selectable but only by clicking on the child divs (i.e. not the empty space inside the div but outside the children)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#all").on("mousedown", function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is(".item-top, .item-bottom") && !$(event.target).hasClass("ui-selected")) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    }
});

$('#all').selectable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).data("isDeselect", $(event.target).is(".item"))
    },
    selected: function(e, ui) {
        if ($(this).data("isDeselect") === true) {
            $(ui.selected).removeClass("ui-selected");
            ui.selected = null;
        }
    }
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1stein/sNMw3/